# C# Simple File Versioning

Tags: c#, file, filesystems, version

Is there a .NET supported way of programmatically versioning basic text, excel, word, etc. files in the file system?

More specifically, I am attempting to add a file version attribute to a Crystal Reports file that is streamed from a Server to the Client when the client requests to run a report. `FileVersionInfo` only supports reading the file version, and `File.GetAttributes` only gets things like `Hidden`, `Readonly`, etc.

Edit: Note that I do not need to keep old versions of these files on the client. I can delete them and replace them with the newer version of the report file. I just need a way to persist the file version on the client side.

```
string path = @"C:\myReport.rpt";

FileVersionInfo myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(path);

Console.WriteLine("File: " + myFileVersionInfo.FileDescription + 
                  '\n' + "Version: " + myFileVersionInfo.FileVersion);

if(File.Exists(path))
{
    var fileAttributes = File.GetAttributes(path);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Windows filesystems don't support versioning directly. You can use some container which does support versioning, but then you'd need to expose the files to the OS in some way.

Comment: So I would be forced to use a config file or some sort of exterior versioning file? I also have the ability to do this in Java, so I looked into using the `UserDefinedFileAttributeView` interface, but after the version is created on the file, Java seems to be the only thing that can view this version. I can't look at the file details to view the version I appended to the file.

Comment: Why not tie in to a version control system?

Comment: I think a version control system would do the trick, but I think it's overkill for this solution. These files will only be downloaded once, or when they are updated, and there won't be too many of them. Updates  to these files _should_ be rare...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain files does not have these attributes. You will have to implement them externaly. this question is asked also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290179/net-write-a-file-with-file-version-information-attached)

According to MSDN:

> Version resources are typically specified in a Win32 resource file, or in assembly attributes. For example the IsDebug property reflects the VS_FF_DEBUG flag value in the file's VS_FIXEDFILEINFO block, which is built from the VERSIONINFO resource in a Win32 resource file. For more information about specifying version resources in a Win32 resource file, see "About Resource Files" and "VERSIONINFO Resource" in the Platform SDK. For more information about specifying version resources in a .NET module, see the Setting Assembly Attributes topic.
>   [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.aspx)

So, there is some native way to store attributes for every file in a separate 'resource' file, but it will include some native method calls, and a .net warper  class.

Comment: Thanks d.popov, I'll have to weigh my options because we didn't want to have a seperate file for versioning if it wasn't necessary.